# Create QR Barcodes on Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, qr-code

I'm creating an app for mac which needs to create QR barcodes as a part of the application.

I've found https://github.com/jverkoey/ObjQREncoder for iOS but couldn't to make it work on my Mac application.

Is there any libraries for generating QR barcodes in Objective-C on Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The QR & bar code encoding and decoding library you're looking for is this (which I've used in a couple of my own projects):

http://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC

It's a full Objective-C port of the ZXing image processing library.  When you build it, it creates *both* iOS and MacOS targets (frameworks and libraries).

Comment: I just tried it. works for every barcode types, but returns nil on QRcode! both result and error is empty. here's my code:

Comment: Sounds like this is a different question.  Why not create a new question and include your code?

Comment: :) sure. Thanks, here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024161/creating-qr-barcodes-with-zxingobjc-on-mac

Answer (score 5):

You can try use `CIFilter` to generate QRCode :

```
static func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> NSImage? {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)

        if let output = filter.outputImage?.applying(transform) {
            let rep = NSCIImageRep(ciImage: output)
            let nsImage = NSImage(size: rep.size)
            nsImage.addRepresentation(rep)
            return nsImage
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Just to add, this works on OS X v10.9 and iOS 7 or later.

Comment: Thank you isaced!  You saved me a mountain of time