# Creating QR barcodes with ZXingObjC on Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, qr-code

I'm trying to use http://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC to create QR codes on my Mac app.

It works for every barcode types, but returns nil on QRcode! both 'result' and 'error' is empty. here's my code:

```
NSError* error = nil;
ZXMultiFormatWriter* writer = [[ZXMultiFormatWriter alloc] init];
ZXBitMatrix* result = [writer encode:@"12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678"
                              format:kBarcodeFormatQRCode
                               width:1750
                              height:1750 hints:[[ZXEncodeHints alloc] init] error:&error];
if (result) {
    CGImageRef image = [[ZXImage imageWithMatrix:result] cgimage];
    self.image.image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image size:NSMakeSize(1750, 1750)];
} else {

    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}
```

What's wrong on it?

Comment: Could you split out your QR code code into a sample Mac app that shows this problem? The sample app in the project is an iOS app and works for me.

Comment: Sure Peter, the sample iOS sample works for me, but on mac, it doesn't create the barcode! I'll create a sample project and post it here to test this.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Here is workaround for this.

1. Open file `ZXingObjC\qrcode\encoder\ZXEncoder.m`
2. Find this row: `int minPenalty = NSIntegerMax;`. There must be a warning on it: **Implicit conversion from 'long' to 'int' changes 9223372036854775807 to -1**. That's the reason of the problem. `NSIntegerMax` returns `9223372036854775807` on my 64-bit Mac and `minPenalty` gets `-1` value (since `int` type cannot store such a big number).
3. Replace the `NSIntegerMax` by `INT_MAX`. It should return the correct value: `2147483647`. That's the number `NSIntegerMax` returns on 32-bit machines according to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800015/what-is-the-maximum-value-of-nsinteger).
4. Run the app and you'll get your QR code!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another method, not this with HINTS, use just:
 
`[writer encode:@"yourmeganumber" format:kBarcodeFormatQRCode width:xxxx height:xxxx error:&error];`
This works for me
Try and let me know

Comment: What would cause one of these methods to work and the other to fail?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I've tried the one without hints, same result! both result and error are nil